# How to enable Office Add-ins on documents served via On Premise Office Online Server

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm trying to deploy Word Add-ins on documents via WOPI hosted application using an On Premise Office Online server.

I have enabled addins on my OOS instance using following Powershell command:

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm - OfficeAddinEnabled:$true
```

However when I open a document and click on Insert/Office Add-ins, I get the following error:
[Error: Please add or enable add-in catalogs from the Trust Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItqLQ.png)

My question is how do I access Trust Center and enable add-in catalogs?

Answer (score 0):

The Trust Center is available in any Office application on the computer by navigating **File | Options | Trust Center**. Depending on whether you are using a network share as the catalog or a SharePoint catalog, you'll find detailed instructions at one of these articles:

- [Publish task pane and content add-ins to a SharePoint app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog)
- [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins)

In the future, please tag questions about Office Web Add-ins with `office-js`.

Comment: I have word of office online server without SharePoint, in my word online application not exist options in file menu.

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour, Did you get a solution to host add-ins in Office Online Server hosted scenario? We are also trying to host add-ins in a web only OOS scenario

Comment: @JoyGeorgeKunjikkuru I have not found a solution yet.